# PHP installation issue on a Windows Server hosted in the Azure cloud

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, azure

I am trying to setup PHP and MySQL on a Windows Server that is currently in Azure cloud using the information from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/11/05/creating-a-wimp-stack-windows-server-iis-mysql-php-on-windows-azure.aspx).

Now I am testing the PHP installation using the methods specified in that tutorial. Here are the steps:

1. Open `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and add an `index.php`.
2. Save the file then go to `xxxx.cloudapp.net/index.php`

But when I do that I get:

```
404 file or directory not found error
```

I can see the default page at `xxx.cloudapp.net` in the browser, but can’t see the PHP file in browser.

Comment: i am checked ,its ok how to check the ownership permissions of that file?.also i have message `restart pending` in server manager console,so how can i restart it?

Comment: Not really a question for superuser. Probably best on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to check:

- Have you enabled PHP over FastCGI with a module mapping?:
  [image]
- Have you added a default document type?
  [image]
- Have you definitely made sure the php file is in the same directory as the default doc page?
- have you recycled the app pools since adding the PHP instance?

Possibly none of these, but these are common pitfalls I've seen when deploying multiple PHP/IIS instances before.

It might be worth following the guide at:
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis
for installing IIS properly on IIS

Also, check that your file extensions are correct.  Some texzt editors will save files as index.php.txt or as index.PHP (note that extensions ARE case sensitive)

Comment: where is this settings given i am new to windows server:)

Comment: look at the screenshots, they show you where the settings are.  Also try following this guide: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: the two thing you mentioned in screenshots are already done.

Comment: does your php file have an uppercase or lowercase extension?? index.php and index.PHP are seen as different files.  You can check in command line by going to cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot and then typing DIR

Comment: i am putting php files in this `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder,also default page of server is present here.

Comment: yep its solved actually filename is saved with `index.php.txt` so i change the folder options to solve the problem.

Comment: Fantastic news.  If this answer helped sovle your proble, please upvote/mark as accepted answer

Comment: Yep this is helped.can you please update  answer with your comments

Comment: I have added extra content onto my answer.